# How to combine a Venn diagram with a decision tree plot in r

Tags: r, decision-tree, venn-diagram

I am trying to combine a plot of a Venn Diagram with a plot of a decision tree but so far no luck.  It seems the plots are not of the same type but I am not able to combine them, since I get an error

Below is some reproducible code:

```
vennPlot <- VennDiagram::draw.pairwise.venn(10000, 7000, 3000, c("First", "Second"), scaled = FALSE)


grid::grid.draw(vennPlot)


library(party)

set.seed(290875)

airq <- subset(airquality, !is.na(Ozone))

airct <- ctree(Ozone ~ ., data = airq, controls = ctree_control(maxsurrogate = 3))


plot(airct, main = "Matched and Unmatched cases applications")


library(grid)

library(gridBase)

library(gridExtra)


layout(matrix(c(1,2), nrow = 1, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))


plot(airct, main = "Matched and Unmatched cases applications")


# second base plot 

frame()

# Grid regions of current base plot (ie from frame)

vps <- baseViewports()

pushViewport(vps$inner, vps$figure, vps$plot)

# Table grob

grob <-  grobTree(grid::grid.draw(vennPlot))

grid.draw(grob)

popViewport(3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be trying to plot the `ctree` object using base graphics but it is grid-based just like the plot from `VennDiagram()`. Below is a working sample.

```
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(ncol = 2)))
pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.col = 1))
plot(airct, main = "Matched and Unmatched cases applications", newpage = FALSE)
popViewport()
pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.col = 2))
grid::grid.draw(VennDiagram::draw.pairwise.venn(10000, 
                                                7000, 
                                                3000, 
                                                c("First", "Second"), 
                                                scaled = FALSE))
popViewport(0)
```

[image]